# How to test individual characters of a bytes string object?

Tags: python, string, byte, pep

Let's say we want to test if the first character of `b"hello"` is a `b"h"`:

```
s = b"hello"
print(s[0] == b"h")      # False   <-- this is the most obvious solution, but doesn't work
print(s[0] == ord(b"h"))  # True, but not very explicit
```

**What is the most standard way to test if one character (not necessarily the first one) of a bytes-string is a given character, for example b"h"?** (maybe there is an official PEP recommendation about this?)

Comment: You could use s.startswith(b"h"). :-)

Comment: @user56700 Nice solution in this case :) I'm looking for something that would work also to test the n-th char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do `s[:1] == b"h"`.

Comment: This works... I'd be interested why?

Comment: @pinegulf `s[:1]` return slice, which is 1 first bytes from `b"hello"` which is `b"h"` , note that `python`'s `bytes` instances support many methods more commonly used with `str`, for example for `s = b"hello"` you might do `s.isalpha()` and it will return `True`

Answer (score 1):

> (maybe there is an official PEP recommendation about this?)

If you mean [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) then so far as I know it does not have any recommendations specific for `bytes` objects.

As accesing *n*-th element of bytes does return integer I would propose following solution

```
s = b"hello"
print(s[0] == b"h"[0])  # True
```